# While writing pandas dataframe to csv file in s3 bucket getting some extra quotes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, amazon-s3

I'm trying to write data from df to csv file in s3 bucket. While writing to csv file in s3 getting some extra double quotes(").

filename:test.csv

```
df:
id |  Name   | Address
_______________________
1  | Ram     | New York
2  | Ram,pal | Mumbai
3  | Toku    | Warsaw
4  | Joku    | SA
5  | Noku    | Tokoyo
```

code:

```
def gen_reports(self, df: str, filename: str):
        """use panda over here"""
        df = pd.DataFrame(df)
        csv_buffer = StringIO()
        df.to_csv(csv_buffer, sep=",", quotechar="'", index=False)
     
        self.s3_client.put_object(Bucket=self.prop.bucket_data, Key=self.prop.key_data + filename,
                                  Body=csv_buffer.getvalue())
```

output:
test.csv

```
id,Name,Address
1 ,Ram ,New York
2 ,"""Ram,pal""",Mumbai
3 ,Toku,Warsaw
4 ,Joku,SA
5 ,Noku,Tokoyo
```

expected result

```
id,Name,Address
1 ,Ram ,New York
2 ,"Ram,pal",Mumbai
3 ,Toku,Warsaw
4 ,Joku,SA
5 ,Noku,Tokoyo
```

Comment: Any help please

Comment: Which version of pandas are you using? Can you update to latest and try again?